# Working out percentage with excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure how to describe this, so I'll try my best. I am currently trying to make a formula that will add 10% to my final cost.

I have the formula currently working out the cost of linear meters from 'R3'. The cost is on per linear meter is on sheet 'Base Rates ! DO NOT DELETE !'. Once the formula works out the cost per linear meter and puts it into column 'AB', I then need it to add 10% which is the our markup. I can't seem to get it to do so.

Please find the formula below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

=SUM(R3*'Base Rates ! DO NOT DELETE !'!B$1)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you take some screenshots (at least of dummy data) of how it looks like and what the expected result should be?

Comment: Added some images to it. Hopefully they're ok.

Comment: It does help, though I wish it could help more. Ok, does that mean for this, you should be getting 119+76.5+41.3 = 236.8, then add 10% markup for the final result of 260.48?

Comment: The three different costs are for three different categories. so it would be R*CAT and then I would require 10% to be added on top of that. Does that make sense? I wouldn't use all three costs in one. The cost depends on which category it falls under.

Comment: What's wrong with =SUM(R3*'Base Rates ! DO NOT DELETE !'!B$1)*1.1  ?

Comment: Would 1.1 be 10%? I suck at math which is why I struggled with it so much

Comment: *The cost depends on which category it falls under*  We need to know is there is any column that shows which category (Cat 1, Cat 2 or Cat 3) should it take. Your formula right now **always** takes Cat 1 (119)

Comment: IF you just need to increase the price by 10%, then @SolarMike is 100% right. Just multiply the cost by 1.1 and you'll get 10%. (1.2 would give 20%, 1,3 = 30% and so on)

Comment: FoxFire. All the formulas are basically the same. The only thing that changes is the cell reference on the Base Rates sheet. At the minute, I am doing that manually by filtering the categories then adding the formula accordingly

Comment: Unfortunately not quite, but I think I'm starting to get in the right direction. In the first screenshot, you need to get the cost for the Budgeted Volume first right? To get that cost, you take the number, taking the first row, it will be 262, then multiply it by the category number, which I think is not shown? Let's say it's category `Cat 1`, so you do 262*119= 31178, which is actually what you have in AFC..? Then do it for all other volumes, add up column FC and add 10% margin? Well I think you only need to do `=SUM('bank'!AB)*1.1` (I don't know the worksheet name, but I see *something*bank

Comment: No need of filtering and doing that if you have any column in your data that shows the category. Take a look at [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: @DougLogan to increase a price by 10% it is price *110 / 100, which can be written as price * 1.1